# Base 52 to decimal And vice versa conversion

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, colors

I am trying to adapt this code that can perform conversions to and from Base 52, which I am using to store RGB color information from C# to C++:

```
public static string ColourToBase52(Color colour)
        {
            int value = colour.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF; // Mask off the alpha channel.
            return ToBase52(value);
        }

        public static Color ColourFromBase52(string colour)
        {
            int value = FromBase52(colour);
            return Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)(0xFF000000 | value)));
        }

        public static string ToBase52(int value)
        {
            char[] baseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            int targetBase = baseChars.Length;

            int i = 32;
            char[] buffer = new char[i];

            do
            {
                buffer[--i] = baseChars[value % targetBase];
                value = value / targetBase;
            }
            while (value > 0);

            char[] result = new char[32 - i];
            Array.Copy(buffer, i, result, 0, 32 - i);

            return new string(result).PadLeft(5, 'a');
        }

        public static int FromBase52(string value)
        {
            char[] baseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            int targetbase = baseChars.Length;

            int multiplier = 1;
            int result = 0;

            for (int i = value.Length-1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                int digit = Array.IndexOf(baseChars, value[i]);
                result += digit*multiplier;
                multiplier *= targetbase;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

For my C++ code, I have opted to combine the functions that get and return the color value as an integer with the Base 52 conversion functions:

```
struct DIFColor *DIFBase52ToColor(std::string c)
{
    const char *baseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int targetBase = 52;

    int multiplier = 1;
    int result = 0;
    const char *d = c.c_str();

    for (int i = c.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {

        int digit = DIFGetPositionInArray(baseChars, sizeof(baseChars), c[i]);

        result += digit * multiplier;
        multiplier = multiplier * targetBase;
    }



    uint8_t b = result & 255;
    uint8_t g = (result >> 8) & 255;
    uint8_t r = (result >> 16) * 255;

    return CreateDIFColor(r,g,b);
}

std::string DIFColorToBase52(struct DIFColor *c)
{
    int rgb = ((c->r&0x0ff)<<16)|((c->g&0x0ff)<<8)|(c->b&0x0ff);

    const char *baseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int targetBase = 52;

    int i = 32;
    char *buffer = new char[i];

    do
    {
         buffer[--i] = baseChars[rgb % targetBase];
         rgb = rgb / targetBase;
    }
    while (rgb > 0);

    char *result = new char[32 - i];

    DIFCopyCharArray((const char *)buffer, i, 0, 32 - i, result);

    std::string s((const char*)result);
    s.insert(s.begin(), 5 - s.size(), 'a');

    return s;

}
```

I also had to create two functions for array manipulation:

```
int DIFGetPositionInArray(const char *array, size_t size, const char c)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

                if (array[i] == c)

                    return (int)i;

    }
    return -1;
}

void DIFCopyCharArray(const char* source, int wheretostart, int wheretocopy, int numtocopy, char *dest)
{
    int c = wheretocopy;


    for(int i = wheretostart; i <= numtocopy; i++)
    {
        dest[c] = source[i];
        c++;
    }


}
```

However, when I tried to test it with a sanity check, it failed:

```
255,255,255 = 'aah1U' in Base52 RGB
aah1U = 1,245,59 in RGB
```

It also seems that every time I run the sanity check, a different value is produced:

```
255,255,255 = 'aah13' in Base52 RGB
aah13 = 1,245,59 in RGB

255,255,255 = 'aah1j' in Base52 RGB
aah1j = 1,245,59 in RGB
```

The expected output was:

```
255,255,255 = 'cpqEN' in Base52 RGB
cpqEN = 255,255,255 in RGB
```

Making me think that this is possibly a pointer problem.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger, step by step and line by line, to see what it does. Keep an eye on the variables and their values.

Comment: Your code has memory leaks and illegal memory accesses. Don’t use pointers everywhere, C++ gets along much better without pointers.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to the array copy function (I think)

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably that you don't terminate the `result` string anywhere, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the following:

```
std::string s((const char*)result);
```

This is because the `std::string` constructor looks for the terminator when copying the C-style string you pass to it.

You can solve it two ways: Either add the terminator character `'\0'` to `result`, or tell the `std::string` constructor the length of `result`.

Comment: After doing this the generated output is not correct, but at least it's the same every time

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that the array copy function is incorrect. It should be:

```
void DIFCopyCharArray(const char* source, int wheretostart, int wheretocopy, int numtocopy, char *dest)
{
    int c = wheretocopy;


    for(int i = wheretostart; c <= numtocopy; i++)
    {
        dest[c] = source[i];
        c++;
    }

    dest[c] = '\0';


}
```

Also, the array search function does not work because `sizeof(baseChars)` returns 4, which is not the number of elements.

Use a function like this:

```
int DIFGetPositionInArray(const char *array, int arrayElements, const char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayElements; i++)
    {

                if (array[i] == c)

                    return i;

    }
    return -1;
}
```

And call it like this;

```
DIFGetPositionInArray(baseChars,52,d[i]);
```